# Sorting column entries in Pandas by name and week

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which I am trying to manipulate and plot. This is tabular data of an entire year of statistics per companies. I would like to plot the earnings of (say) Google each week for a decade. So, I know I have to splice together several years of data in the form of arrays. However, I am not sure how to organize this data in terms of weeks.

(1) How do I search columns do find only 'Google' and (2) how can I plot this by week? I think I would have to sum from days 1-7

```
fname = "file.csv"

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(rita1989)

data.columns
#OUTPUT ..., 'Date', 'DayWeek',..., 'Companies', ..., 'Earnings'

01/05/2008 7    Yahoo       5678.89
01/06/2008 1    Google      3486.84
01/07/2008 2    Google      2379.23
01/08/2008 3    Ask         3578.22
01/09/2008 4    Google      2341.10
01/10/2008 5    DuckDuckGo  8410.00
```

Comment: To use only 'google' data, then use `data[data['Companies'] == 'Google']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
data['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).to_period('W-SAT').to_timestamp(how='end')
data[data['Companies']=='Google'].groupby('week')['Earnings'].sum()
```

I suspect there's a more elegant way to get the week variable than what I'm doing.

This should also work, but we have to make the index the date:

```
data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date'])
goog_totals = data['Earnings'].resample('w', how='sum').dropna()
```

At that point, you can just plot with `goog_totals.plot()`.